# Codigo PHP se ejecuta por si solo?

Tags: php

Buen día,

Tengo un script PHP el cual envía un correo con ciertas variables que vienen recibidas por medio del metodo POST y a su vez guarda en una base de datos MySql mencionada info.

Tuve un problema y es que se enviaban correos por si solos como si algo en el servidor ejecutara el script, llegando vacios aun así cuando en el .js (por medio de Ajax) no permitía que se enviaran los datos al .php hasta que el usuario llenara todos los datos por lo cual me imaginé que se ejecutaba solo el PHP y no que quizá el .js enviaba datos "burlando" esa validación de no enviar datos vacíos.

ese problema del correo lo corregí validando en el .php que las variables no estuvieran vacías (lo cual es obvio no deben estar vacías por la validación en el .js), aquí la validación

```
if (!empty(@$_POST['nuevo_id'] && @$_POST['nombre'] && @$_POST['celular'] && @$_POST['direccion'] && @$_POST['correo'])){

//aquí envío el correo y solucioné que no se enviarán correos solos sin información
}
```

resulta y pasa que el código que guarda la info en la base de datos (que son exactamente las mismas variables usadas para enviar el correo), el cual quedó por fuera del if, se ejecuta solo así como pasaba con el correo, esto me genera que hayan registros vacíos en la base de datos, en 3 días ya tenia 250 registros nuevos todos en blanco, imagino que la solución sera igual a la del correo y es lo que probaré, poner el código que guarda en la base de datos dentro del if que me valida que las variables no estén vacías mi pregunta es:

Eso a que se debe? por que se ejecuta el código solo?, es necesario que siempre que haga consultas MySql oi enviar correos tenga que validar los campos aunque sea obvio que no deben estar vacíos? o debo agregar algo adicional, les dejo la consulta por si algo:

```
$agregar_info_usuario = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE `gabriel_SoftwareTecflucol`.`solicitudes`
SET `nombre`='$nombre',
`celular`='$celular',
`email`='$correo',
`ruta_foto1`='$ruta_final_foto1',
`ruta_foto2`='$ruta_final_foto2',
`direccion`='$direccion',
`comentarios`='$comentarios'
WHERE `solicitudes`.`id`='$nuevo_id';");
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: si es posible muestra todo el codigo php de tu archivo. la información que has proporcionado no hace denotar errores.

Comment: Si se esta enviando el correo por si solo, no es magia, solo no se esta controlando. Te aconsejo validar primero el `insert` en tu base de datos si y solo si los registros se insertan con éxito, pues envíes el correo @Gabriel Uribe Gomez

Comment: Si por ejemplo tú haces submit de un formulario y el mismo llama a un PHP, debes evitar que el PHP se ejecute usando `preventDefault` u otro método parecido, o de lo contrario, se ejecutará el PHP que tenga el formulario en la etiqueta `action`.  Eso por un lado. Por otro, por lo que veo, **te faltan muchas validaciones y controles** por establecer, no solamente en el código, el cual no *debe hacer lo que le plazca*, tú eres el programador y eres quien debes decirle al código lo que debe hacer. Por otra parte, la base de datos tampoco debería admitir valores en blanco o duplicados.

Comment: @A.Cedano como podría hacer lo que mencionas de que la base de datos no reciba datos en blanco?

Comment: Cuando declaras la tabla, debes poner la restricción `NOT NULL` a aquellos campos que siempre deberán tener datos, por ejemplo el campo `nombre`.  De ese modo, no se hará ninguna inserción cuando en alguno de esos valores con la restricción `NOT NULL` intente ingresarse un valor nulo. Otra restricción que debería tener tu tabla es la de no duplicados (`UNIQUE`), agregando dicha restricción a la/s columnas que jamás podrán ser iguales en dos o más filas de la tabla.

Comment: Por favor quita las @ de tu código es feo y una mala práctica.  Tu `empty` no puedes encerrar todo en `empty`, **debes aplicarlo individualmente a cada una de las variables que quieras comprobar**. En cuanto a impedir que se ejecute el resto de código si la validación falla puedes utilizar la sentencia `exit` en el `else` de la validación.

Comment: @Xerif el código del if lo copié de otro lado, en si para que son las @?

Comment: @GabrielUribeGomez Las arrobsa son para silenciar los errores. Puedes encontrar una explicacion completa aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @Xerif Gracias mi hermano!

Answer (score 0):

> Codigo PHP se ejecuta por si solo?

**Sí**

PHP evalúa (*ejecuta*) TODO el código cuando mandas llamar algún script. A menos que separes el código en funciones, y mandes llamar esas funciones de forma condicional. Entonces, las funciones solo se ejecutarán cuando las condiciones adecuadas se cumplan.